# The method getApplicationContext() is undefined for the type AlarmReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

In my app in mainActivity I created an alarm manager object

I am calling a broadcastreceiver class AlarmReceiver.

In that class I am initialising a database object but it is showing the error

> The method getApplicationContext() is undefined for the type
>   AlarmReceiver"

How can I overcome this.

AlarmReceiver.java

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
     @Override
     public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
       Toast.makeText(arg0, "Alarm received!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       DatabaseHandler1 db = new DatabaseHandler1(getApplicationContext());
     }
}
```

In mainActivity

```
Date dat  = new Date();//initializes to now
Calendar cal_alarm = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar cal_now = Calendar.getInstance();
cal_now.setTime(dat);
cal_alarm.setTime(dat);

cal_alarm.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
cal_alarm.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 55);
cal_alarm.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
cal_alarm.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

if(cal_alarm.before(cal_now)){  //if its in the past increment
  cal_alarm.add(Calendar.DATE,1);
}

Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(),1, intent, 0);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal_alarm.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

Comment: replace `atabaseHandler1 db = new DatabaseHandler1(getApplicationContext())` with `atabaseHandler1 db = new DatabaseHandler1(arg0)` or `atabaseHandler1 db = new DatabaseHandler1(arg0.getApplicationContext())`...

Comment: you have `Context arg0` as the param

Comment: still have same error

Comment: Check your `DatabaseHandler1` input parameter. Is it a `Context` ?

Comment: then post your `DatabaseHandler1` class constructor definition...

Answer (score 0):

Look at the method for onReceive()

```
public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1)
```

You are passing the context as a parameter. You should use that context.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `arg0`.You don't need to use `getApplicationContext()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


     @Override
     public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
         Toast.makeText(arg0, "Alarm received!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            DatabaseHandler1 db = new DatabaseHandler1(arg0);


     }
}
```